# Linking an Angular library to an Angular app throw an error after calling the page via localhost

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

#### Linking an Angular library to an Angular app throws the following error:

```
core.mjs:6494 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'bindingStartIndex')
    at Module.ɵɵelementStart (core:14545:1)
    at GreenTextComponent_Template (libs-my-lib.mjs:13:199)
    at executeTemplate (core.mjs:9632:1)
    at renderView (core.mjs:9432:1)
    at renderComponent$1 (core.mjs:10739:1)
    at renderChildComponents (core.mjs:9297:1)
    at renderView (core.mjs:9457:1)
    at renderComponent$1 (core.mjs:10739:1)
    at renderChildComponents (core.mjs:9297:1)
    at renderView (core.mjs:9457:1)
```

For reproduction purposes I have created a very simple Angular app und library.
The app simple uses the library to display some green text.

**Library**:
https://github.com/obas9000/my-lib

**App**:
https://github.com/obas9000/my-app

Using node `v14.15.0 (npm v6.14.8)` everything works fine.
Since using `v16.15.0 (npm v8.5.5)` the above described error appears.

Steps:

1. Clone the lib
2. `cd pathToLib/my-lib`
3. `nvm use 16.15`
4. `npm i`
5. `npm run build`
6. `npm run link`
7. Clone the app
8. `cd pathToApp/my-app`
9. `nvm use 16.15`
10. `npm i`
11. `npm link @libs/my-lib`
12. `ng serve`
13. go to localhost:4200

I  you use `nvm use 14.15` everything would work without any error.

Does anybody has an idea how to solve this error?